# Please help me translate these english sentence into Predicate calculus. I have hard time doing it.

Tags: predicate-logic

1. Everything is greater than or equa to itself;
2. For evert number n, the resut of adding n to 9 is greater than or equal to 9;
3. Everything has something greater than it.

This is for my semantics homework, I tried to first question, but I think I got it wrong, My answer is ∀X1[greater(X1)∨equal(X2)]. Please correct my first question and help me with next two questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't want two variables for the first sentence. You want $\forall x(x\geq x)$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\forall x[x\mbox{ is greather than }x \vee x\mbox{ is equal to x }]$

2.$\forall n:[ n+9\mbox{ is greather than }9 \vee n+9 \mbox{ is equal to }9]$ Where $n+9$ denotes the result of adding n to 9

3. $\forall x, \exists y:[ y\mbox{ is greather than }x]$

Comment: Assume that in $U$ you have the order-relation given by $(U,<)$

Comment: Thanks so much. I have a question for all the examples that I've seen in the handouts involve brackets. Ex. Everything is black or white: ∀x2[black(X2)∨white(X2)]. Do you think these two questions should include brackets too?

Comment: emm, you can do this: let $p(x):\{x\in U: \mbox{ x is black }\}$ and $q(x):\{x\in U: \mbox{ x is white }\}$ two propositions, then $\forall x\in U, p(x)\vee q(x)$ Also brackets notation is ok.

Comment: If it is helpfull for you, you can vote-up in the check place closer the answer.

Comment: Sorry for having so more questions, but in our class we don't use "U" in translation. "everything is black or white ->∀x2[black(X2)∨white(X2)]" that's the example that my teacher gave us. She wants us to have same format as that example.  So in the three examples I post it, is there anyway I can avoid using U and add bracket to it to make it simiar to the example?  I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Okey, i fixed it. You can check now and if you have some question let me know. Don't forget vote-up if everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

The first can be written as $\forall{x}.x \ge x$, or $\forall{x}.x \gt x \vee x = x$ if the language doesn't include $\ge$.  Your answer looks almost right, but the predicates "greater" and "equal" each require two arguments and you have an unquantified variable X2.  In the same style I would write the answer as ∀X1[greater(X1,X1)∨equal(X1,X1)].

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes it makes sense to me

Comment: that's my typo. My classmate answered it as "∀X2[(X2>X2)∨equal(X2=X2)] what do you think of this one?